# Get changed variable form other Class?

Tags: java, android, class, variables

So, I start the App, and in the onCreate method of the MainActivity I change the variable value. But when I click the button, which gets me to an other Activity, and in this Activity I try to get the changed variable, I get only the original value of the variable.

So, my problem here is that I don't know how to get the changed variable from the first class. How do I do that?

here is the code:

Main Activity:

```
package com.example.getandset;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //Initialised variable
    String tag;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //The text that I want to show in the next class
        setTag("Show this text");
    }

    public void setTag(String t){
        tag =t;
    }

    public String getTag(){
        return tag;
    }

    public void onClick_Start(View v){
//start of the next Class
        startActivity(new Intent(this, CalledActivity.class));
    }

}
```

and Called Activity:

```
package com.example.getandset;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CalledActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_called);

        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
//trying to get the changed variable
        tv.setText("Got text: "+ new MainActivity().getTag());
    }


}
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html topic: Starting Another Activity

Comment: You can append your tag as an extra to the intent or put it to the shared preferences.

Comment: you want to get passing value from called Activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void onClick_Start(View v){
 //start of the next Inten
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, CalledActivity.class)
   intent.putExta("key",getTag()) ;
   startActivity(intent );
}
```

get passing tag text from CalledActivity   into onCreate method

```
String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a new instance of `MainActivity` that has `tag` initialized to `null`. In general, you should never instantiate an `Activity` like this, always let the system start them, using `startActivity`.

There are several ways to achieve the effect you want:

- pass the tag in the intent that starts `CalledActivity`
- use persistent storage to transfer the tag value from one activity to the other.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have data calls such as this from the Main activity. It is not the same as an object class, and thus the behavior is different. (the issue lies in the fact that you are calling the class, not an initialized instance of an object)

What you need to do is start the activity using an INTENT which contains a data bundle.

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

(this is straight from the android dev guide)

then in the second activity, you use

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

you can do this with any number of variables/types of variables.

your other option, is to create an object class to "hold" the variables. Pass that object the same way as above, and then call the variables from the class as normal with .getVariable();